# How to compare two images pixel by pixel and frame new image from the dirty part of image

Tags: java, image, image-comparison, dirtyread, dirtyrectangle

I am capturing the screen using `robot.screenCapture()` and frame `bufferedImage1`. Again I am capturing desktop screen and frame `bufferedImage2`.

Could please tell me how to compare these 2 images (`bufferedImage1` and `bufferedImage2`) pixel by pixel. If there is any difference, then how to frame the part that is different?

Comment: how would you recognize dirty part of image ?

Comment: that is what I am asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

1. Compare the entire images, get the percentage of pixels that differ more than a threshold.
2. Divide into quarters recursively, down to a certain size, and get the same percentage for each quadrant.
3. Draw the frame around the quadrants that are a certain amount above the average difference. If you need square sections, use a single quadrant based on size and percent difference. Otherwise, you can combine more than one quadrant with large differences.

Comment: could you please tell me how to compare 2 images and  get the percentage of pixels that differ more than a threshold.

Comment: You can compare each image pixel by pixel using system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel. You can speed it up at the cost of precision by resizing the images to a smaller resolution before you start.